# Amplitude of a sound wave

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics

What is the largest displacement of an air molecule for a sound wave of 261.6 Hz with intensity 1 $\frac{W}{m^2}$? I am not sure how to find the energy of a sound wave.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework-and-excercises question, I will not provide the whole answer, just give hints. First, read through the wikipedia on sound measurements ([here and follow the other links as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_displacement)).

I would go this way:

- Calculate the $SWL$
- Presume $SWL = SVL$ (or do the appropriate corrections)
- Get $v$ from $SVL$
- Integrate the $v$
- Be aware of RMS values